# signalr.client.httpclientexception statuscode 404 exception when passing through hubConnection.Start().Wait()

Tags: c#, signalr, client, console-application, iis-6

We are unable to connect to a signalR hub deployed on server (Windows Server 2008 Enterprise SP2 and IIS 6) through a console application, we tested everything locally on a PC and it was working fine, but deployed on a server (IIS 6) we became unable to connect remotely or even locally on the server itself.

No experience in SignalR but the same client is working fine on a normal PC. (client and hub in the same pc).
We tested the connectivity and the permissions to the server and it's all fine.
We are able to reach the hub url (http://hr1/HRNotificationHub) when we call it remotely via a web browser , but when we add signalR/hubs we get 404 error in the browser also.

static void Main(string[] args) //Client
            {
                try
                {
                    IHubProxy _hub;

```
                string url = @"http://localhost/HRNotificationHub/";

                var connection = new HubConnection(url);
                _hub = connection.CreateHubProxy("HRHub");
                connection.Start().Wait();

                _hub.On("ReceiveMessage", x => Console.WriteLine(x));

                string line = null;
                while ((line = System.Console.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    _hub.Invoke("BroadcastMessageToAll", line).Wait();
                }

                Console.Read();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException.ToString());
                Console.Read();

            }
        }


    public class Startup //Server
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);

            var hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration()
            {
                EnableDetailedErrors = true,
                EnableJSONP = true,
                EnableJavaScriptProxies = true
            };

            app.MapSignalR(hubConfiguration);
        }
    }


    [HubName("HRHub")]
    public class HRHub : Hub //Hub Class
    {
        public void BroadcastMessageToAll(string message)
        {
            Clients.All.newMessageReceived(message);

            var newMessage = message + "-newmessage";
            Clients.All.ReceiveMessage(newMessage);
        }

        public void JoinAGroup(string group)
        {
            Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, group);
        }

        public void RemoveFromAGroup(string group)
        {
            Groups.Remove(Context.ConnectionId, group);
        }

        public void BroadcastToGroup(string message, string group)
        {
            Clients.Group(group).newMessageReceived(message);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Locally, it is working under IIS Express, which is normal.

On the server though, you are running IIS 6 which is not a supported version. Please check the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/supported-platforms). You need at minimum IIS 7, but IIS 8 if you expect to use web sockets.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, all I have done was adding the line in the webconfig of the project deployed on the server:
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />

Answer (score 0):

All what I have done to solve this issue was adding the line in the webconfig of the project deployed on the server:

```html
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
```